# Using PubNub History API with iOS

Tags: ios, pubnub

How does one receive the history of a channel using the History API? In the documentation it says that a call to `[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:myChannel from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:YES];` returns an array on success, yet my compiler asserts that the return value is void. The documentation for that method and related methods say that they "Fetch messages from history", but I can't seem to figure out where the messages are fetched to. Is there a delegate method that the messages are sent to? Please help me out.

Thank you

**EDIT**

The messages are now being received, but not according to the time interval specified. I am receiving all messages on the channels.

```
- (void)subscribePostChannels:(NSArray *)results withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!error) {
        static int SECONDS_IN_TEN_DAYS = 864000;
        for (PFObject *post in results) {
            if ([post.createdAt timeIntervalSinceNow] > (-1) * SECONDS_IN_TEN_DAYS) {
                [self.channelsToSubscribe addObject:post.objectId];
                NSString *pushChannel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"channel_%@", post.objectId];
                [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] addUniqueObject:pushChannel forKey:@"channels"];
            }
        }
        NSArray *channels = [PNChannel channelsWithNames:self.channelsToSubscribe];
        [PubNub subscribeOnChannels:channels];
        // Now retrieve messages
        NSDate *lastLogin = [PFUser currentUser][@"lastActive"];
        for (PNChannel *channel in channels) {
            [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:channel from:[PNDate dateWithDate:lastLogin] includingTimeToken:YES withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *array, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Last Active: %@", [PFUser currentUser][@"lastActive"]);
                    if (channel == [channels lastObject]) {
                        [PFUser currentUser][@"lastActive"] = [NSDate date];
                        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error Fetching History: %@", error);
                }
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error finding messages. Post channels not subscribed.");
    }
}



- (void)subscribePostChannels:(NSArray *)results withError:(NSError *)error
{
    static int SECONDS_IN_TEN_DAYS = 864000;
    for (PFObject *post in results) {
        if ([post.createdAt timeIntervalSinceNow] > (-1) * SECONDS_IN_TEN_DAYS) {
            [self.channelsToSubscribe addObject:post.objectId];
            NSString *pushChannel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"channel_%@", post.objectId];
            [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] addUniqueObject:pushChannel forKey:@"channels"];
        }
    }
    NSArray *channels = [PNChannel channelsWithNames:self.channelsToSubscribe];
    [PubNub subscribeOnChannels:channels];
    // Now retrieve messages
    for (PNChannel *channel in channels) {
        NSDate *lastLogin = [PFUser currentUser][@"lastActive"];
        [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:channel from:[PNDate dateWithDate:lastLogin] to:nil];
    }
}
```

The log messages are indicating that lastActive occurs after the messages that are being received from history.

Comment: What code are you running that calls subscribePostChannels: withError:?

Comment: The main issue I see in your above code: 1) that subscribe will not run, unless you are already connected to PubNub via the connect() method. Have you already connected somewhere else in code you did not provide? 2) If you are already connected, then the connect completion block where you embed the history call will never execute, because you are already connected.

Comment: Does moving [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:channel from:[PNDate dateWithDate:lastLogin] to:nil]; from within the connect success block, to outside the connect block, just after your subscribe call, make things work?

Comment: Yes, I am already connected. I connect first thing in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Ok, if you are already connected, then you must remove the history call from the success block on the second connect request. Does this fix the issue for you?

Comment: Yup, that does it for me. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: However, the full message history is being sent, not just the messages since the date specified.... I've updated to show my current code and the new problem

Comment: please contact us at support@pubnub.com for this latest issue, it will be easier to share code on this new issue via a support ticket.

Answer (score 3):

My second problem, with all messages being displayed instead of just the ones I wanted, was because the PubNub History API is set up such that in:

```
[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:myChannel from:nil to:nil limit:100];
```

the `from:` date is considered the date to start backtracking from, and then you retrieve all messages prior to that date up until the `to:` date. I thought that `from:` was supposed to be the earlier date in time, which is not the case.

So for me to receive all messages from the point of last login up until the current date i needed to use:

```
[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:myChannel from:nil to:[PNDate dateWithDate:lastLogin] limit:100];
```

Thanks to Craig from PubNub support for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, let me know if it works for you:

In my ViewController.m :

```
PNConfiguration *myConfig = [PNConfiguration configurationForOrigin:@"pubsub.pubnub.com" publishKey:@"demo" subscribeKey:@"demo" secretKey:@"demo"];

[PubNub setConfiguration:myConfig];
[PubNub connectWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *origin) {

    PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"{BLOCK} PubNub client connected to: %@", origin);

    PNChannel *myChannel = [PNChannel channelWithName:@"a" shouldObservePresence:YES];
    [PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:myChannel from:nil to:nil limit:100];

}

                     errorBlock:^(PNError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError.code == kPNClientConnectionFailedOnInternetFailureError) {
        PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"Connection will be established as soon as internet connection will be restored");
    }

    // UIAlert code, etc

}];
```

And in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessageHistory:(NSArray *)messages forChannel:(PNChannel *)channel
    startingFrom:(NSDate *)startDate to:(NSDate *)endDate {

PNLog(PNLogGeneralLevel, self, @"PubNub client received history for %@ starting from %@ to %@: %@", channel,
        startDate, endDate, messages);
```

}

And I see output from the delegate such as:

```
2014-07-31 11:12:41.076 PubNubDemo[70859:60b] AppDelegate (0x8e25eb0) PubNub client received history for PNChannel(0x93261e0) a starting from PNDate (0x9330d90) <date: 2014-07-31 18:10:43 +0000; time token: 14068302439622999> to PNDate (0x9330e30) <date: 2014-07-31 18:12:40 +0000; time token: 14068303601434709>: (
"PNMessage (0x9329650): <message: ***********.... 1861 - 2014-07-31 11:10:43, date: (null), channel: a>",
"PNMessage (0x9330830): <message: ************... 1862 - 2014-07-31 11:10:45, date: (null), channel: a>",
"PNMessage (0x9330850): <message: *************.. 1863 - 2014-07-31 11:10:46, date: (null), channel: a>",
"PNMessage (0x9330870): <message: **************. 1864 - 2014-07-31 11:10:47, date: (null), channel: a>",
```

More info on the delegates here:

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#--voidpubnubclientpubnub-client-didreceivemessagehistorynsarray-messages-forchannelpnchannel-channel-startingfrompndate-startdate-topndate-enddate

And more info on the observers here:

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#observation-center

Does this guide you in the right direction?

geremy

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'll edit original post to show how I am trying to call it.

Comment: Thank you for editing your original post to clarify.